# sed: regular expression,how to substitute?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have those line on a text file

```
36) 
SIGCANCEL
37) 
SIGLOST
38)
SIGXRES
39)
SIGJVM1
40)
SIGJVM2
41)
SIGRTMIN
42)
SIGRTMIN+1
43)
SIGRTMIN+2
44)
SIGRTMIN+3
45)
SIGRTMAX-3
46)
SIGRTMAX-2
47)
SIGRTMAX-1
48)
SIGRTMAX
```

I want to substitute using sed so the lines become

```
SIGRTMAX-3
SIGRTMAX-2
SIGRTMAX-1
```

I have tried those commands,but none work

```
sed s/^[0-9]\)//g
sed s/^[0-9])//g
```

also using the -e switch produce nothing.

Comment: Try `sed s/^[0-9]\+)//`

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work

Comment: `sed s/^[0-9][0-9]*)//`

Comment: This yes,works thanks,put as asnwer,i can vote it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute is not needed, you can simply delete lines starting by a digit :

```
sed '/^[0-9]/d'
```

And if you really must use substitution :

```
sed 's/^[0-9].*//'
```